# Comparison of commercially available components

Tags: artificial-satellite, commercial

I am researching for a student developed nanosat mission, and would like to know which companies to buy from. The sensors are sun sensors and magnetometers. The actuators are magnetorquers. Can anyone please point me to a site that does a comparative study of all commercially available components and helps me choose?

Comment: I take it you mean space-qualified components?

Comment: What is the mission profile and duration? If LEO and 2 weeks, say, COTS (commercial-off-the-shelf) might work, but no guarantees. You might end up with an orbiting doorstop. If NEO or Van Allen Belts or magnetosphere, forget COTS.

Comment: This type of questions is not much liked on Stack Exchange. Please read https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping. You should edit your question to ask about criteria, not for shopping recommendations.

Answer (score 3):

I take you mean space-qualified parts? So far as I know, there isn't one specific site.

What is the mission duration and profile?

Try the product, supplier and company searches [here](http://www.epiqspace.com/), [here](http://www.edn.com/search?keyword=sun%20sensors), and [here](http://www.edn.com/search?keyword=magnetometer). Also try [here](http://mwrf.com/) and [here](http://sourceesb.com/).

You can try also the industry one-stop shops like this [one](http://mouser.com) - search several countries, this [one](http://element14.com), or this [one](http://rscomponents.com). There's lot's more.

For an national space agency's perspectives, try http://nepp.nasa.gov, and the NASA Parts Selection List https://nepp.nasa.gov/npsl/. I don't know what the equivalents are for ESA, CNES, or DLR, or the Italian national space agency. If you find out, please let me know in a comment.

A reference of interest to you might be this [paper](https://nepp.nasa.gov/DocUploads/2ED1FADF-B443-4038-8292DC44387FC3B3/commspce.pdf), for starters.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know of any all-inclusive review of the available COTS hardware for small satellites. NASA does, however, have a nice paper detailing/discussing current technology for small spacecraft, which I would recommend checking out -https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/Small_Spacecraft_Technology_State_of_the_Art_2014.pdf

"Small Spacecraft" in the paper are defined to be <180kg, however it has an emphasis on CubeSat-related technology. It is not exclusively focused on COTS hardware, but even if you do not find a specific sensor or magnetorquer you want to use, I think it is worth it to read through the sections on the subsystem(s) you are in charge of. I had a similar project to you and found their discussion on the subsystem I was charge of to be quite helpful.

If you do not find the specific hardware you are looking for, I would recommend you check out Clyde Space (http://www.clyde-space.com/) and Innovative Solutions In Space (http://www.isispace.nl/cms/), which both have a strong selection of CubeSat/nanosat components to choose from.